# Add and delete lines in file after match

Tags: awk

please help me with this:

I have a file named: demo.txt, the content of demo.txt is:

```
[default]
exten=>test1,hint,SIP/202
exten=>tom,hint,SIP/233

[toyota]
exten=>test1,hint,SIP/202
exten=>tom,hint,SIP/233

[girls]
exten=>test1,hint,SIP/202
exten=>tom,hint,SIP/233
```

I want a script to add more line AFTER [toyota], I need something to do something like this:

```
[default]
exten=>test1,hint,SIP/202
exten=>tom,hint,SIP/233

[toyota]
exten=>another,hint,SIP/202
exten=>well,hint,SIP/202
exten=>test1,hint,SIP/202
exten=>tom,hint,SIP/233

[girls]
exten=>test1,hint,SIP/202
exten=>tom,hint,SIP/233
```

I need another script to remove a line located UNDER [toyota]
Example, I want delete:

```
exten=>well,hint,SIP/202
```

Please, tell me how can i do that in a simply clean way

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want to add more lines from another file or just manually enter them. If it is the latter then you can do the following to add new lines:

```
awk '/^\[toyota\]/{print $0; print "exten=>another,hint,SIP/202" RS "exten=>well,hint,SIP/202";next}1' demo.txt
```

To remove certain lines:

```
awk '/^\[toyota\]/{p=1}p&&/exten=>well,hint,SIP\/202/{p=0;next}1' demo.txt
```

Comment: @Manuel Do you mean it **does not** work or it **does** work? :)

Answer (score 0):

if sed is an option:

To add the lines

```
sed '/^\[toyota\]$/ aexten=>another,hint,SIP/202\nexten=>well,hint,SIP/202' demo.txt
```

To delete the line

```
sed '/^\[toyota\]$/, /^\[/ {/exten=>well,hint,SIP\/202/d}' demo.txt
```

Comment: Hi It works fine, but It can delete using sed. It says error.

It says:

[root@Linux shm]# sh del.sh
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unknown command: `2'
[root@Linux shm]#

Comment: @Manuel, oops...have to escape the `/` before 202, try the edited answer now

Comment: How to add and delete a line after ;(toyota)